# CSS rotate div 10deg full width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have found the [following Website](http://teufels.com/de/).
Special the Section: Social News on the half of the side.

I wonder how to get the rotated divs (i think about 10 deg) over the full width. 
Is there any possibility to do that responsive? So i can use the rotated div on a mobile phone?
I`m not as fit to rotate the div. How can i do this using css?

I`ve tried this:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Ans using following css:

```
.container {
   transform: rotate(10deg);
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   background: red;
}
```

But the Container is not full width.

Comment: You can use transform: rotate(10deg); which just turns the element

Comment: As well as transforming by rotation, you could also scale it up, and set the `div` parent 's `overflow` style to `hidden` - which, if scaled up enough, should cover the full width.  I think thats what you're asking about ..?  i.e.  `transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It work's without transforms. There are only [CSS-Shapes](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/). It's possible with transforms too. On [A Collection of Separator Styles](https://tympanus.net/Development/SectionSeparators/) there are many other separator styles.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
}

.outer::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  
  border-top: solid 40px #ffffff;
  border-right: 100vw solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  
  content: '';
}

.outer::after {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  
  border-bottom: solid 40px #ffffff;
  border-left: 100vw solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  
  content: '';
}


.inner {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 60px 1em;
  
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">…</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#div {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Using a negative value rotates it counter-clockwise.

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="rotated"></div>
```

CSS

```
.rotated {
    transform: rotate(10deg)
}
```

---

If this is what you are talking about, it's not a rotated div. That whole slideshow part is just an image.
[image]

UPDATE: 
It's is supported in IE9. Reference: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform%3A%20rotate

Comment: Is it still necessary to account for IE9/Safari?

Answer (score 0):

As well as transforming by rotation, you could also scale it up, and set the div parent 's overflow style to hidden - which, if scaled up enough, should cover the full width.

```css
div.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

div.container {
  margin-top: 42px;
  transform: rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="container"></div>
</div>
```